# When using SQL bigquery and uploading bike_hire table. I try to preview, and all fields show as nullable, even though I can still query it

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

bigquery_public_data
NY bike_rides
bike_hire

Comment: only the first preview pages show `null`. The last page is fully filled. Please check for nulls by `SELECT starttime ,count(1) FROM bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips group by 1 order by 2 desc`

Comment: Thankyou for your help, I am still learning.